# 3D Fillet in OpenSCAD?

Tags: 3d, openscad

Is there a 3D filler in OpenSCAD or a library to handle it?  Ideally something reasonably fast (not the `minkowski_difference` stuff available which can take hours to days.)  I was able to get a nice looking 2D-generated fillet on the individual necks of this flask but reformatting to use 2D fillets isn't an option where they come together because in this case there is no radial symmetry:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code so that we can study the problem more closely?

Comment: @ScottLeslie A simplified version would be the union of two spheres slightly offset from eachother line in the attached photo.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but hope it helps someone.

A fillet over an arbitrary 3d edge can be an incredibly intense mathematical formulation, depending on the specific geometry of the edge.

Packages like SolidWorks or AutoCAD include functions to calculate these arbitrary fillets. They also cost thousands of dollars. Part of that fee is going to making those nice design features.

OpenSCAD is free. It doesn't have any of those nice design features. We have to do it all ourselves.

---

**Thankfully** most of the fillets we will want to do aren't arbitrary. They are pretty well defined and pretty tame mathematically.

For example, we can make a filleted box using a `hull` on 8 spheres positioned at the edges of a cube.

We can also use `rotate_extrude` on a circle to create a ring that we then use in a `difference` to cut away material around circular joints to create fillets there.

I would say *most* fillets that you would want to make could be described by toroids or `hull`s (or a combination). You just have to construct the object in a slightly different way than you would usually think about it.

Comment: Not so sure a hull approach would work here - given it's to create a fillet in an edge around a hollow area, where the fillet itself would be more of a negative space (so a hull would just result in a flat line between the two hollow hemispheres.)

Comment: Yes, in your specific case of filleting the union of three spheres you will need to use three toroids and two spheres to describe the shape of the curve you need.

Comment: That would give an outward curve, not an inward one.

Comment: I would point you to remembering that the only difference between outward curves and inward curves is `difference()`.

Comment: Not really.  In this case the depth of a difference would be arbitrary while the thickness of the spheres is very small.